# Joining same table based on whether employees were at location or not

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have a table as follows:

```
 year_id | loc_id | emp_id | freq 
 ---------------------------------
  1990   |   LA   | fred_01| 55   
  1990   |   LA   | mury_01| 34
  1990   |   BA   | fred_01| 20
  1990   |   CA   | mury_01| 40
  1990   |   MO   | fred_01| 100
  1990   |   PR   | bill_01| 500
```

I want everything grouped by the year and loc, but the tricky part
is I want to get the sum of all "freq" at each location, then also get
the sum of all the employees "freq" that worked at that location, when they're at another location (but not including original loc amount).

Desired results of first two rows:

```
 year_id | loc_id | sum(freq) loc | sum(freq)away 
 ------------------------------------------------
 1990       LA    |   89          |  160
 1990       BA    |   20          |  155
```

I can do one at a time with an INNER JOIN, but when i try to get both sums, everything gets messed up:

```
select t1.loc_id , t1.year_id,sum(t2.freq),sum(t3.freq) from emp_freq t1
inner join emp_freq t2 
  on t1.year_id=t2.year_id and t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id and t1.loc_id=t2.loc_id 

inner join emp_freq t3 
on t1.year_id=t3.year_id and t1.emp_id=t3.emp_id and t1.loc_id<>t3.loc_id

group by t1.loc_id,t1.year_id
order by t1.loc_id,t1.year_id
```

If i comment out the second inner join, the result for the grouped by loc is correct.

Comment: Your code makes a common mistake where what is wanted is the join of aggregations (maybe of joins) but people wrongly try to do all joining first then all  aggregatiing after. You could find this faq by, as we always should, googling many clear, concise, precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal before considering posting. If you do post then use one phrasing as a title. PS "everything gets messed up" is too vague to be helpful. Always give a [mcve] in a code question.

Comment: Well i didnt know my mistake so i couldnt google/think of a description...But thanks, because your exactly right...This comes up often for me. So now i know (Joining before the aggregation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution, that uses two levels of aggregation.

First, aggregate records by year, location and employee, with an inline correlated subquery that compute the time spent by the employee this year at another location.

```
SELECT 
    year_id, 
    loc_id, 
    emp_id, 
    SUM(freq) freq,
    (SELECT SUM(freq) FROM emp_freq t1 WHERE t1.year_id = t1.year_id AND t1.emp_id = t.emp_id AND t1.loc_id <> t.loc_id) other_freq
FROM emp_freq t
GROUP BY year_id, emp_id, loc_id
```

Then, we just need to group once again the resultset, this time without the employee in the non-aggregated columns, to compute the totals:

```
SELECT year_id, loc_id, SUM(freq) freq, SUM(other_freq) other_freq
FROM (
    SELECT 
        year_id, 
        loc_id, 
        emp_id, 
        SUM(freq) freq,
        (SELECT SUM(freq) FROM emp_freq t1 WHERE t1.year_id = t1.year_id AND t1.emp_id = t.emp_id AND t1.loc_id <> t.loc_id) other_freq
    FROM emp_freq t
    GROUP BY year_id, emp_id, loc_id
) x GROUP BY year_id, loc_id
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qFA6GVdxA86EaCRjFjB5Hg/0)** with your sample data returns :

```
| year_id | loc_id | freq | other_freq |
| ------- | ------ | ---- | ---------- |
| 1990    | LA     | 89   | 160        |
| 1990    | BA     | 20   | 155        |
| 1990    | MO     | 100  | 75         |
| 1990    | CA     | 40   | 34         |
| 1990    | PR     | 500  |            |
```

Comment: This seems like a tidy solution. I was hoping a second solution would show another technique without the subquery.

Comment: @denutza : yes, that's how it is... for this requirement, one way or another you need two passes...

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select year_id, loc_id, sum(freq) as loc,
       (select sum(e3.freq)
        from emp_freq e2 join
             emp_freq e3
             on e2.emp_id = e3.emp_id and
                e2.year_id = e3.year_id
        where e2.loc_id = e.loc_id and
              e2.year_id = e.year_id and
              e3.loc_id <> e2.loc_id
       ) as other_freq
from emp_freq e
group by year_id, loc_id;
```

Your data has no instances of a year/employee/location combination being duplicated.  This might not do what you want in that case.